# NSLayoutConstraint and setting a view X pixels from top in portrait and Y pixles from top in landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

Want a table view to appear 300 pixels down from the top while in portrait and about 175 pixels from the top while in landscape.

i can't seem to figure out the VFL logic i need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like many autolayout problems, yes, you can do what you're asking, but it's far from obvious. If I really needed precisely 300pt or 175pt, I might, too, be tempted to adjust the top constraint on rotation.

But if you want to know how to do this without handling rotation events, you could:

1. Set a required minimum top margin of 175;
2. Set a lower priority preferred top margin of 300 (which won't be satisfied in landscape); and
3. Less obviously, you also need a required minimum height too (so that in landscape, it will know not to satisfy the lower priority request to make the top margin 300).

You could, for example, use (obviously replace my bottom margin of 5 with whatever makes sense for you, but adjust the minimum height of the tableview accordingly):

```
@"V:|-(>=175)-[tableView(>=120)]-5-|"
```

combined with:

```
@"V:|-(300@500)-[tableView]"
```

(Obviously, you would have constraints for the horizontal axis, too, but I omit those for the sake of brevity.)

This is, admittedly, vaguely unappealing, to have to precisely specify the minimum table height, too, but I saw no other way to tell autolayout under what situations it should gracefully not satisfy the optional top space of 300pt.

---

You can also do this with using the the *y = mx + b* formula of `constraintWithItem`. Yes, I know you asked how to do this with Visual Format Language, but if you use `constraintWithItem`, you don't have to specify the minimum table height, but rather you can just set the top margin like so:

```
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:self.tableView.superview
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                         multiplier:multiplier
                                           constant:constant];
```

Clearly, the trick is how to determine the `multiplier` and `constant` so that you get 300 pt in portrait and 175 pt in landscape. Doing a little algebra, you will see that you can calculate those values as follows:

```
CGFloat multiplier = (300.0 - 175.0) / (superviewPortraitHeight - superviewLandscapeHeight);
CGFloat constant = 175.0 - superviewLandscapeHeight * multiplier;
```

(And, again, I'll assume that you'll specify the other constraints so that the tableview is not ambiguously defined, e.g. set the left, right, and bottom constraints, which can be done in Visual Format Language.)

Comment: Awesome, the constraintWithItem works perfect. It makes some sense and should be able to use it other places where i'll need to do the same things. I guess i wanted to do this with constraints cause it was my understanding constraints are suppose to replace the need to use the rotate orientation delegate (like rdelmar suggested)?

Comment: @Log139 Yeah, longer-term, Apple wants developers to focus on logic conditional on the `bounds` of a superview rather than the orientation of a device. But part of me wonders whether autolayout is really ready for primetime. It's too complex. There are some noticeable deficiencies in VFL. There's also a cognitive dissonance between the flexibility of autolayout and device and orientation-specific digital assets. I tip my hat to you for your enthusiasm, but for me, the jury's still out. Personally I hesitate to declare the above code as an improvement over traditional approaches.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@"V:|-(>=175)-[tableView(>=120)]-5-|"`?

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers Yes, I believe so. Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anyway to set this up to do specific distances without changing it in code in a rotation callback method. If you make an IBOutlet to the constraint in IB (lets call it con1), and have that constraint with the initial value of 300, then in a rotation callback method you can just change that constant.

self.con1.constant = 175;

**After Edit:**

this works:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        con1.constant = 175;
    }else{
        con1.constant = 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Log139, I think you could move it closer to the top that way, but I don't know if you can get that exact number (175). If you have a constraint to both the top and the bottom, and give the top one a lower priority, it will keep the higher priority distance (to the bottom), and make the distance to the top smaller when you rotate. If the height of your view is just right, then that distance might be 175.

Comment: i was kinda thinking the same thing, but i'm not sure how i would set up the logic.

Comment: not exactly 175, but close. something like V:|-(<=300@500)-[myView]-(>=500@750)-|? so the top would be at most 300 pixels and the bottom would be greater then 500 pixels? if its greater then 500 pixels, it would be in portrait, less would be in lanscape...

Comment: @Log139, I think that might give you an ambiguous situation, besides, if you have to do it in code, then the way I said in my answer is easier, and will give you the exact number you want.